# Codeigniter $this->lang->line(errors) without paragraph tags for tank auth error messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

I'm wondering if someone can help me with this. I am currently trying to integrate tank auth into my codeigniter site. I am slowly getting there but have run into a minor stumbling block in that when I have moved the error messages from being displayed as part of an html view to a javascript alert they are still printing out the paragraph tags around the error message.

The error messages which are passed to my login form as an array/ or multidimensional array I think are produced in the controller by the following lines of code:

```
$data['errors'] = array();
foreach ($errors as $k => $v)   $data['errors'][$k] = $this->lang->line($v);
```

Here is my code for displaying the error messages:

```
if ((isset($errors[$login['name']]))||(isset($errors[$password['name']]))||(form_error($login['name']))||(form_error($password['name']))){
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("';
}
echo form_error($login['name']);
echo isset($errors[$login['name']])?$errors[$login['name']]:'';
echo form_error($password['name']); 
echo isset($errors[$password['name']])?$errors[$password['name']]:'';
if ((isset($errors[$login['name']]))||(isset($errors[$password['name']]))||(form_error($login['name']))||(form_error($password['name']))){
        echo'")</script>';
}
```

Now my primary question here is how to remove the paragreaph tags ande I have found a clue here in the codeigniter documentation:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html
They key part here is that It says you can set the delimeters for the errors on the upload script by doing this:

```
$this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
```

But I have no idea how and where to apply this to tank auth.

I also have a second question which I would be grateful to anyone who can answer, I am slightly confused by the code for displaying the error messages. For example:

```
echo form_error($password['name'])
```

can someone explain this to me, it has no $ at the beginning so is not a variable so whats it all about, and the thing I am really trying to get to is how to simplify my logic in checking for the error messages, since it is incredibly long winded at the moment and there are a lot of error messages to handle.

I appreciate there is a lot to deal with here but any help/explainations will be gratefully recieved.

Comment: i have the issue codeigniter can't show the line information like if you do this->lang->line('auth_username_in_use') it does not print anything

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To remove the tags wrapping the error message, you'll have to call the `set_error_delimiters()` method of the Form Validation object with 2 empty strings as the parameters.

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
```

More on this: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#changing-the-error-delimiters

As for your second question, I'm not sure what you're asking actually. It's only a function call where the returned value of the call will be outputted to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your help that worked perfectly, no Im not entirely sure what Im asking in the second part, I'll try to work that out before I come back.